# Grabbing long text from SQL Database with ColdFusion, output truncated

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have a SQL database with a `ntext` field which holds page content.

I am using ColdFusion to query the information and deliver it to a form.

The form utilises ckeditor for this particular field, the field at present contains around 4000 characters. When looking in the ckeditor window it appears some of the text is missing.

However, when I look at the database data the text is not truncated at all; it is completely intact.

I thought this might be a character limitation with ckeditor, so I turned it off and viewed the data through a textarea box but the text is still missing.

The query is a simple select query held within a component, nothing special:

```
<cfquery name="getDrilledContent" datasource="#application.dsn#">
        SELECT co.uid_content, co.txt_contentgroup, co.txt_contentRefID, co.uid_contentuser, co.txt_contentvalue, co.dte_contentdate, co.txt_contentpagename,
        co.txt_metatitle, co.txt_metadescrip, co.txt_metakeywords, co.txt_metaurl, co.bit_primary, co.txt_h1, co.txt_contenturl, co.txt_contentlink,
        us.txt_du_firstname, us.txt_du_surname, txt_du_email, dte_edited, uid_changedby
        FROM tbl_content co 
        INNER JOIN tbl_datausers us ON co.uid_contentuser=us.uid_datauser
        WHERE uid_contentwebid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#session.webid#">
        <cfif Isdefined('arguments.uid_content') AND arguments.uid_content NEQ "">
        AND co.uid_content=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.uid_content#"></cfif>
</cfquery>
```

Why isn't this query pulling all the data down?

Comment: Not to worry I've worked it out! It was a cold fusion administrator setting, under datasource settings. CLOB - Enable long text retrieval. I checked the check box.

Jason

Comment: Check your content. Sometimes if it has actual quotes( " ") in it it will close the text field that powers the ckeditor... this goes for all text fields rather than just the ckeditor ones.

Comment: Make sure you post your comment as an answer and mark it as accepted so future readers won't have to locate the fix in your comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not to worry I've worked it out! It was a ColdFusion Administrator setting.

Under **Data & Services -> Datasources**, edit the datasource, and click the **Show Advanced Settings** button. This reveals additional options, one of which is **CLOB - Enable long text retrieval**.

I checked the check box, and the problem was resolved.